# Upon setting environment variables in sqlite3 in windows 10 home desktop, why can I not open databases?

Tags: sqlite, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

In windows 10 on desktop home edition I set the following 'system variable' in `PATH` `C:\sqlite3\` now when I go to command prompt in admin mode or not I can start up sqlite3 by using the command `sqlite3` however when I open a database this way it will not read the tables in such database, unless I specify the full directory of the database file location.

Going into the exact same database but by double clicking on file `C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.exe` I can then view the tables in the exact same database absolutely fine without specifying the full directory.

Why can't I start this program from the command line successfully overall?

Would it be something to do with how I am setting my environment variable for this sqlite3, because I presume this is the thing that is incorrect but after much searching on google and on here I can not find any other way of doing it.

- Googled
- Tried pointing directly to exe in environment variable
- Searched stack overflow

**UPDATE**

I found out when running from the command line its actually creating the database file by default in `C:\Users\mynamehere` I can't figure out exactly why, but my best theory is that its something to do with how I am setting the environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will search the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable to find *executables*, like `sqlite3.exe`.

From the [SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html):

> Start the sqlite3 program by typing "sqlite3" at the command prompt,
>   optionally followed by the name the file that holds the SQLite
>   database. If the named file does not exist, a new database file with
>   the given name will be created automatically. If no database file is
>   specified on the command-line, a temporary database is created, then
>   deleted when the "sqlite3" program exits.

`cmd` will *not* search the directories in the `PATH` environment variable to find the database file. It will look for (or create) the database in the current working directory. Therefore, you must use full (or relative) path. Another option would be to `cd` to the directory where the database lives, then execute `sqlite3 {databasename}`

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, is well answered. I think for now I will stick to just the auto generated one in C:\Users\mynamehere as this seems the most straight forward method for me.